# Is the taxicab metric equivalent to the euclidean metric

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $p$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ be points in Euclidean space. Is the closest point to $p$ amongst $q_1$ and $q_2$ with the taxicab metric always the same as with the Euclidean metric ? In other words, do both metrics always produce the same ordering of distances ?

Motivation : I am looking to optimise a program that needs to compare distances very often, but where the actual value of said distances are unimportant as long as the order does not change.

Comment: The points $(n,n)$ and $(2n,0)$ have the same distance to the origin in L1, but vastly different in L2. So if you wiggle them a bit you can get all kinds of counterexamples

Comment: Let $v=(10^{-4},1-10^{-4})$ and $w=(7/10,7/10)$. You can check directly with a calculator that $(\lVert v\rVert_2-\lVert w\rVert_2)(\lVert v\rVert_1-\lVert w\rVert_1)<0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio: $v=(1,10), w=(7,7)$ might not even need a calculator since $11<14$ and $\sqrt{101}>\sqrt{98}$

Comment: For an easy integer-only counterexample, try (4,3) and (6,0) relative to the origin. In Euclidean, 5<6, in taxicab 7>6.

Comment: I think that if two metrics preserve the same order, then the two metrics will agree on which points are equidistant. In other words, a circle in one metric (all points at a fixed distance to a centre point) will also have to be a circle in the other metric. You could for example use the squared euclidean distance, which saves you calculating any square roots.

Comment: That is Correct , @JaapScherphuis , which was why I selected a Circle in my Answer , to highlight that ; More-over , "Equidistant Points via taxicab Metric which are on a line" will not match "Equidistant Points via Euclidean Metric which are on a Circle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With loss of generality , we  can take $P = Origin$.
Let us make a Circle with $Center = P$ & Distance to $Q1$ is the radius.
Here , we can take the $angle = 45$ Degree.
We can also take $radius = 1$ , through scaling.
Euclidean Distance $ED(Q1)=1$ , while taxicab Distance $tc(Q1) = \sqrt{2}$.

Let us consider a line at $angle = 30$ Degree where $Q2$ may lie.
Let $Q2$ move from little inside the Circle to a Point on the Circle & then to little outside the Circle.
Here , $tc(Q2)$ varies on this line.

### Intuitively :

**We can tell which is nearer to $P$ , when looking at $ED(Q2)$.**

**We can NOT tell which is nearer to $P$ , when looking at $tc(Q2).**

[image: DISTANCES]

### Numerically :

When $ED(PQ2) = 0.99$ , $tc(PQ2) = 0.99\sin{30}+0.99\cos{30} = 1.352365$
When $ED(PQ2) = 1.00$ , $tc(PQ2) = 1.00\sin{30}+1.00\cos{30} = 1.36602540$
When $ED(PQ2) = 1.01$ , $tc(PQ2) = 1.01\sin{30}+1.01\cos{30} = 1.3796856578$

Here , $tc(Q1) = 1.41421356$ , hence we can NOT tell which is nearer in Euclidean Distance , with the taxicab values.